# TLS connection error 'This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7

I am performing an upgrade of a web application for which I have to configure the website on IIS10 on a new server. While setting up, I had provided DNS which is exactly same as the DNS on the old server.

To access the newly configured website I have paused old IIS and I am accessing the new one. Then I am getting below error

> *This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening, try contacting the website’s owner.*

What could be the reason, is it because both, old and new have the same DNS?
Is there anything that I need to find out? I have checked with `eventvwr`, nothing is shown there.

Also note, TLS 1.0, 1.2 values are active.

Comment: "Also note, all TLS, SSL values are active" is the red flag. A modern server should leave only TLS 1.2 enabled and several weak ciphers should also be disabled. A site like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ can teach you more.

Comment: My bad, TLS 1.0, 1.2 are active. i will update the post.

Comment: You should read from various sources that TLS 1.0 is not secure any more, https://www.comodo.com/e-commerce/ssl-certificates/tls-1-deprecation.php No public site should allow TLS 1.0 now.

Comment: first try to clear browser cache an cookie. enable TLS 1.2 in internet explorer and SSL 3.0 disabled [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHocV.png).Allow Mixed Content To Display [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BScrb.png)

Comment: I found out that it was due DNS was not corrected.